# What's wrong with this folder path declaration? Throws 'UnexpectedValueException'

Tags: php, wordpress, file-io

```
DEFINE ('PAGES', '/pages/');
$directory_pages = new DirectoryIterator(PAGES); //ERROR LINE
foreach ($directory_pages as $files) {
    if ($files_pages->isFile()) {
        $file_name_page = $files_pages->getFilename();
        $my_page_content = file_get_contents(PAGES. $file_name_page);
    }
}
```

This code is located in a plugin, where the "pages" folder that I'm trying to access is inside the plugin itself.

So the script is myplugin.php and it resides in the folder "myplugin", which has a subfolder, "pages".

I'm trying to load the files in the "pages" directory, but my path reference is throwing an error. Do I need to use ABSPATH here instead?

Or perhaps a dynamic method to get the current directory relative to root of WordPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual says:

> Throws an UnexpectedValueException if the path cannot be opened.

Basically, if `/pages` is not a valid directory, then it won't work. To be relative to the current working directory you would use `pages` without the leading slash.

I'm not familiar with Wordpress, but if it supplies a valid base constant prefix to use, then I would prepend that to the path you are using.